# Alinear elemento a la derecha - Boostrap 4.5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Llevo unos días intentando acomodar el dropdown "cuenta" al lado derecho pero no lo he conseguido, aquí abajo envío el código que tengo actualmente para el navbar.
Gracias de ante mano.

Como se ve:

[image: Como se ve actualmente]

Como espero que se vea:

[image: Así es como quiero lograr que se vea]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://startonmc.com/user/assets/img/theme/stmclogo.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-center" alt="" loading="lazy">
        StartonMC
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Cuenta
              </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logear</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Registrar</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Panel</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo una solución para ti.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://startonmc.com/user/assets/img/theme/stmclogo.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-center" alt="" loading="lazy">
        StartonMC
    </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
      
    <li style="list-style: none" class="nav-item dropdown ">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Cuenta
              </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logear</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Registrar</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Panel</a>
                </div>
            </li>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Para que tu elemento se viera a la derecha del navbar debía estar fuera del `ul` del nav.
Automáticamente se va a la izquerda.

Espero que esto funcione para ti.
Si tienes dudas adicionales, estaré encantado de ayudarte.